# Installing subversion using rpm

Tags: redhat, rpm

I have been given a remote Red hat Terminal and asked to install subversion. 
The only instructions I have is

```
pull rpm client svn distro and unpack it using rpm2cpio filename.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

how does on pull rpm distributions ?

Comment: That's a **terrible** instruction. That isn't **at all** the right way to install an RPM. That's a reasonable way to get the contents of an rpm into the current directory though. Perhaps asking whoever gave you this instruction for clarification would be a more appropriate avenue than SO?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a really good reason not to, use the package manager by running `yum install subversion`  Using the package manager makes it much easier to update and maintain the system in the future.

Here's a link to the official [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/collaborating.svn.html)